# Pandas Dataframe- Drop columns if all the values with the column are either 0,1,nan

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Assuming this is the dataframe. I looking to drop the columns if all the values within columns are either 0,1, NaN.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,0,0,0], [0,0,1,0],[2,'NaN',1,0]])
```

[image]

End result should be just first column "0" and drop remaining columns.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
lst = [0, 1, 'NaN']

mask = df.isin(lst).all(axis=0)
df.drop(mask.loc[mask].index, axis=1, inplace=True)
```

it will essentially ensure you drop all columns, for which all values are in `lst`.

Answer (score -1):

use this:

`df.drop([1,2])`

See also [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html)

Comment: It would be helpful for your to explain your answer. You might say check the pandas doc. Well, to noobs like me, that is also confusing. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html One helpful thing would be to state the answer with named parameters: df.drop(labels=[1,2]) OK, slightly less confusing. But does this even work? It might work for that specific data set, but I don't think it satisfies the intent of the question - does it?